# Floating-point division imperfection

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, division

I know that the floating-point is not perfect, either it's `float` or `double`, but does it mean that, when I divide one floating-point number by another and the the dividend is divisible by the divider without a reminder (like 10000.0 is divisible by 10.0), is it possible that I get a number with .99999999... at the end which is only smaller than the correct result by a tiny fraction. Can such thing happen with floating-points?

I need to know because I need to apply `floor` function after the division and it would make a huge difference if floating-point divisions are really that imperfect.

Comment: Yes it is possible, read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic][1]. [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Going by the C/C++ standard, it would be implementation defined behavior. Going by IEEE, if the result is exact, it will be exact. i.e. `1000 / 10` will never yield `99.9999999`

Comment: If you want 100% precision, then you can design and implement a class that supports all the arithmetic operations over a rational number (comprised of an integer numerator and an integer denominator). For example, see a fully tested such class at https://github.com/barakman/Num.

Comment: @40two What makes you think that the document you cite supports the answer “yes”? I think it supports the answer “no”, specifically the sentence “In addition to the basic operations +, -, × and /, the IEEE standard also specifies that square root, remainder, and conversion between integer and floating-point be correctly rounded.”

Comment: @PascalCuoq The standard doesn't say much about the implementation of the floating point types (even if IEEE is nearly universal). AFAICT, it's legal for `10 / 1.` to return `-375.456` if the implementation has a "lot of rounding error".

Comment: In short, floating point numbers are in *binary*. So you should be thinking about fractions in binary. Basically, as long as you have enough precision and range, enough bits in mantissa and exponent, dividing and multiplying by 2 only increments/decrements exponent, and is accurate. Anything else (including conversion of decimal number in source code to binary float) is more complex.

Comment: @Mysticial: Annex F of the C11 standard describes C support for IEC 60559, which is basically IEEE 754 under a different name. In particular, for any implementation that defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`, `float` is binary32, `double` is binary64, and `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` are the IEEE 754 `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` operations, which must be correctly rounded in accordance with the IEEE standard.

Comment: @Mysticial Hold on, I am having the “I didn't read it but WECSSKAFPA says that IEEE 754 arithmetic is always approximate” discussion, I can't be sidetracked into the “the C standard doesn't actually mandate IEEE 754” discussion. :)

Comment: By the way, an interesting corollary is that you can do exact division even when the there is a remainder: first use `fmod` to extract the (*always* exact) remainder and subtract it off, then perform the exact division that remains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> does it mean that, when I divide one floating-point number by another and the the dividend is divisible by the divider without a reminder (like 10000.0 is divisible by 10.0), it's possible that I get a number with .99999999... at the end

No. IEEE 754 division is correctly rounded. If there is a representable floating-point number (1000 in your example) for the result, this is the result you will get for the division.

What can happen is that you do not divide the numbers you are thinking, because you wrote `0.1` and you think that this represents the mathematical value 0.1. In this case the end result can be surprising, but this is no fault of the floating-point division.

As long that you know that you are dividing the numbers you mean, if the mathematical result of the division is, say, an integer below 2<sup>24</sup>, then the result of the floating-point division will be that integer.

Comment: So no matter how large or small the numbers are, as long as they represent natural numbers without fractional part and one is divisible by another, I get no fractional part in the resulting number after the division, on any CPU when compiled with GCC/MVC?

Comment: No, only if all three numbers, the two inputs and the result, are exactly representable.

Comment: @DesmondHume “no matter how large or small the numbers are, as long as they represent natural numbers without fractional part…” Yes, but note that some natural numbers larger than 2^24 cannot be represented as a `float` (the limit is 2^53 for `double`). “on any CPU” This would have to be a CPU (and a compilation platform) that implements IEEE 754 at least approximatively. Any of IA-32, x86-64, or modern ARM incantations would qualify.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the hardware is using IEEE 754 floating point division, the key issue is whether the natural number operands are exactly representable.

First of all, the formats have finite range. The natural numbers do not. However, even the 32-bit binary floating point limit, around 10^38, is large enough for most practical purposes.

Within that range, it comes down to whether a natural number can be expressed as `1.x*2^n` where `n` is an integer and `1.x` is a binary fraction with no more than 23 bits after the binary point. All natural numbers that fit in 24 bits meet that condition. So do all powers of two that are in range.

In general, larger floats, with bigger exponents, have bigger gaps between consecutive values. Up to 24 bit naturals, the gap is no greater than 1, so all the natural numbers are representable. At the next step, the gap is 2, then 4, then 8 ... as the exponent increases.